# results of soup.find are none despite the content exisiting

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to track the price for a product on amazon using python in jupyter notebook. I've imported bs4 and requests for this task.

When I inspect HTML in the product page I can see `<span id="productTitle" class="a-size-large">`

However when I try to search for it using `soup.find(id = "productTitle")` The results come out as `None`

I've tried using `soup.find` other id and classes but the results are still `None`

`title = soup.find(id="productTitle")`
This is my code to find the id

If I fix this I hope to be able to get the name of my product whose price I will be tracking

Comment: what is the url and name of the product?

Comment: the product is called Apple iMac ME088LL/A 27-Inch, 1TB Hard Drive - 8GB Ram. url = https://www.amazon.com/Apple-iMac-ME088LL-27-Inch-Drive/dp/B00M4LWO8O/ref=br_asw_pdt-6?pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_s=&pf_rd_r=NS8CATQZ6Z5EH2WZG925&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=f05a98e0-3eaa-471e-b2f1-f6d8d5a04287&pf_rd_i=desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That info is stored in various places in return html. Have you check your response to see you are not blocked or getting an unexpected response?

I found it with that id using and strip

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00M4LWO8O/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('#productTitle').text.strip())
```

Also,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00M4LWO8O/')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print(soup.select_one('#imgTagWrapperId img[alt]')['alt'])
```